# Getting smallest number in array python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, minimum

I am trying to program in python

I have an array which holds data like

[A,20,False] [B,1,False] [C, 8, False]

I want to be able to loop through the array by getting the element with the lowest middle number so e.g. the next element to be worked on would be B because it has the smallest number one. Then this gets deleted so then the next element to be used would be C because out of 20 and 8 8 is the smallest number...

hope ive made this clear

Please help

Thank you

Comment: This isn't very clear.. Is this a multidimensional array, i.e. `[[A][20][False]][[B][1][False]][[C][8][False]]`, or is the content a string like `"A,20,False"`?

Comment: sorry a multidimensional array

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> myList = [["A", 20, False], ["B", 1, False], ["C", 8, False]]
>>> smallest = min(myList, key=lambda L: L[1])
>>> smallest
['B', 1, False]
```

If you'd like to sort it using that element you can do the same thing with `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(myList, key=lambda L: L[1])
[['B', 1, False], ['C', 8, False], ['A', 20, False]]
```

Comment: i get the following error:AttributeError: Node instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Can you post the code that got you that error?  The stuff I pasted above was run as-is in the Python interpreter and you can see the results.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the item with the smallest number:

```
from operator import itemgetter

next = min(array,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

You can also sort the list using the second item as the key:

```
array.sort(array,key=itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the list and then loop through it as you said:

```
somelist = [[A,20,False] [B,1,False] [C, 8, False]]
somelist.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x[1], y[1]))

for smallest in somelist:
    # do stuff with the smallest member
```